# cmd and ftp.exe error WScript.Shell

Tags: vbscript, ftp

Hoping for some help

I am using this script to ftp to one of my servers.

```
<% 
   Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
   cmdLine = "c:\windows\system32\ftp.exe -v -i -s:C:\windows\system32\ftp.exe -s:"+Request.Form("website")+"" 
   tempRet = oShell.Run("c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c " & cmdLine, 0, true) 
   set oShell = nothing
   waitTime = numberOfFiles * 2 
   startTime = Timer

   do while timer < startTime + waitTime 
   loop 
%>
```

I suddenly get this error code, and can just not figure it out.

> error 'fffffffe'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
cmdLine = "c:\windows\system32\ftp.exe -v -i -s:C:\windows\system32\ftp.exe -s:"+Request.Form("website")+""
```

seems to have two + symbols. This converts the cmdLine variable to an int with value 0. Replace the crosses with pretzels (&).
I do not know if that is the source of the problem, but it is definitely not correct.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
cmdLine = "c:\windows\system32\ftp.exe -v -i -s:C:\windows\system32\ftp.exe -s:"+Request.Form("website")+""
```

seems to be have the ftp executable as the value to the `s:` option. Possibly a copy n' paste error? `s` needs to be given a filename that includes ftp commands

Answer (score 0):

We were getting this error on the server, it was fixed when the server restarted.

Comment: But is there a way to make the error not happen in the first place?